# PHP: Variable in a function name

Tags: php, variables

I want to trigger a function based on a variable.

```
function sound_dog() { return 'woof'; }
function sound_cow() { return 'moo'; }

$animal = 'cow';
print sound_{$animal}(); *
```

The * line is the line that's not correct.

I've done this before, but I can't find it. I'm aware of the potential security problems, etc.

Anyone? Many thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do that, but not without interpolating the string first:

```
$animfunc = 'sound_' . $animal;
print $animfunc();
```

Or, skip the temporary variable with [call_user_func()](http://php.net/call_user_func):

```
call_user_func('sound_' . $animal);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You saved me a lot of irritation!

Comment: This is an intriguing method. Is it a security risk to give a REQUEST variable direct access to this? If so, what measures can be taken to prevent it? Perhaps a list of functions that you only want to give access to, and a check against this list when the REQUEST var of this name is encountered?

Comment: You should not give REQUEST direct access (read: ALWAYS sanitize user input).  A dispatch table along the lines of Greg Hewgill's answer is probably the best solution.  You can check validity of the REQUEST input via array_key_exists(), just make sure you quote the values (sound_dog -> 'sound_dog') or it'll throw a notice.

Comment: @scribble: not true `(#sound_$animal")();` will call the function `sound_dog` if `$animal` is `"dog"`. Using `call_user_func` is not needed.

Comment: @theking2 did you meant `("sound_$animal")();` ?

Comment: @Lionel-fr I might actually have

Answer (score 17):

You can do it like this:

```
$animal = 'cow';
$sounder = "sound_$animal";
print ${sounder}();
```

However, a much better way would be to use an array:

```
$sounds = array('dog' => sound_dog, 'cow' => sound_cow);

$animal = 'cow';
print $sounds[$animal]();
```

One of the advantages of the array method is that when you come back to your code six months later and wonder "gee, where is this `sound_cow` function used?" you can answer that question with a simple text search instead of having to follow all the logic that creates variable function names on the fly.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not proper syntax. As `sound_dog` is interpreted as a constant but not defined, PHP silently converts it into `'sound_dog'` which than can be called in the way you describe, with warnings though. It works for now but perhaps not in the future. A proper definitions would be `$sounds = [ 'dog'=> 'sound_dog', 'cow'=> 'sound_cow']`

Answer (score 6):

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

To do your example, you'd do

```
$animal_function = "sound_$animal";
$animal_function();
```

Comment: I would select this as the proper answer for brevity instead of @scribble.

Answer (score 2):

You can use curly brackets to build your function name. Not sure of backwards compatibility, but at least PHP 7+ can do it.

Here is my code when using Carbon to add or subtract time based on user chosen type (of 'add' or 'sub'):

```
$type = $this->date->calculation_type; // 'add' or 'sub'

$result = $this->contactFields[$this->date->{'base_date_field'}]
                   ->{$type.'Years'}( $this->date->{'calculation_years'} )
                   ->{$type.'Months'}( $this->date->{'calculation_months'} )
                   ->{$type.'Weeks'}( $this->date->{'calculation_weeks'} )
                   ->{$type.'Days'}( $this->date->{'calculation_days'} );
```

The important part here is the `{$type.'someString'}` sections. This will generate the function name before executing it. So in the first case if the user has chosen 'add', `{$type.'Years'}` becomes `addYears`.

Answer (score 2):

For `PHP >= 7` you can use this way:

```
function sound_dog() { return 'woof'; }
function sound_cow() { return 'moo'; }

$animal = 'cow';
print ("sound_$animal")();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself why you need to be doing this, perhaps you need to refactor your code to something like the following:

```
function animal_sound($type){ 
    $animals=array(); 
    $animals['dog'] = "woof"; 
    $animals['cow'] = "moo"; 
    return $animals[$type];
}

$animal = "cow";
print animal_sound($animal);
```

Comment: 1 function that does the same thing as 2 functions?

Comment: C mindset? Using a hash table?  More like the maintainable code mindset.

Comment: 99% of the time, you'd be right. This is in a virtual <i>sea</i> of code, and I can only remember doing it once before. Where it comes in handy, however, is when you have a whole bunch of very similar functions, like:

search_book_amazon();
search_book_bn();
search_book_z3950();
... 20 more

In cases like that...

<pre>if($type == 'amazon') { search_book_amazon(); }
if(type == 'bn') { search_book_bn(): }</pre>

just adds another point of failure, and is annoying to type to boot.

Comment: I wish my PREs worked in comments. What, when we comment we can't use code?!

Comment: Maybe you need a search class.

Comment: Couldn't you just do search_book('amazon') and search_book('bn')..?

Also I'd use a switch statement rather than the array listed above.

Comment: @recursive it's not the has table I have a problem with. I'd like to see it more functional, with each animal value being a function that is maintained outside animal_sound by attaching it to an animal object. When animal_sound is called (if you need it at all), you pass it the animal object and the animal sounds himself. In OOP, it works nice. In normal PHP, you may need to emulate closures in LISP to do the same thing. The C mindset is making 1 common function that you call, and everytime you want to extend the functionality, you need to edit that function until...

Comment: ...it is so huge, you end up refactoring it into several functions anyway, that aren't really all that well decoupled or reusable. It isn't the hash table that causes the problem, it's the design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->` and `self::` for class-functions. Example provided below with a function input-parameter.

```
$var = 'some_class_function';
call_user_func(array($this, $var), $inputValue); 
// equivalent to: $this->some_class_function($inputValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another solution to what I like to call the dog-cow problem. This will spare a lot of superfluous function names and definitions and is perfect PHP syntax and probably future proof:

```
$animal = 'cow';
$sounds = [
    'dog' => function() { return 'woof'; },
    'cow' => function() { return 'moo'; }
];

print ($sounds[$animal])();
```

and looks a little bit less like trickery as the "string to function names" versions.

JavaScript devs might prefer this one for obvious reasons.

(tested on Windows, PHP 7.4.0 Apache 2.4)