# Function name inside a variable

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a simple question (i guess).
I'm getting the name of the function inside a variable from database. After that, i want to run the specific function. How can i echo the function's name inside the php file?
The code is something like this:

```
$variable= get_specific_option;
//execute function
$variable_somesuffix();
```

The "somesuffix" will be a simple text. I tried all the things i had in mind but nothing worked.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777820/php-variable-in-a-function-name. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Here's some sample code to show you how it works, and the errors produced:

```
function get_specific_option() {
    return 'fakeFunctionName';
}

$variable = get_specific_option();

$variable();
// Fatal error: Call to undefined function fakeFunctionName()

$test = $variable . '_somesuffix';

$test();
// Fatal error: Call to undefined function fakeFunctionName_somesuffix()
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
 function hello($name="world")
 {
     echo "hello $name";
 }

$func = "hello";

//execute function
call_user_func($func);
> hello world

call_user_func($func, "byron");
> hello byron
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this. Assuming:

```
function foo_1() {
  echo "foo 1\n";
}
```

You can use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$var = 'foo';
call_user_func($foo . '_1');
```

or do this:

```
$var = 'foo';
$func = $var . '_1';
$func();
```

Unfortunately you can't do the last one directly (ie `($var . '_1')();` is a syntax error).

Answer (score -1):

You can also do sprintf($string).