# How can i call a function when the name is a variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Variable in a function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777820/php-variable-in-a-function-name)

I have some functions and i use variables to know there names.
ex. $func1 = "do_something"; is there any way to call do_something() function ;

Comment: if($funct1=="do_something") do_something();
I wish more indeligent just to learn if there is way like ${$funct1)() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function do_something( ) {
    return 'I did something';
}

$function = 'do_something';
echo $function( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function like so:

```
$func1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$func1();//ta da
```

Or you can do:

```
call_user_func($func1);
```

Comment: Actually, this works even in PHP 4.

Comment: @BerryLangerak yea.... I was confusing it with anon functions...

Answer (score 0):

Just call it `$func1()`.

[read on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)